# calling virtual method without pointing to an object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void init()
    {
        internal_init();
    }
    virtual void internal_init()
    {
        std::cout << "internal of A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B: public A {
    void internal_init()
    {
        init();
        std::cout << "internal of B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    B instance;
    std::cout << "internal of A" << std::endl;
    instance.internal_init();
    return 0;
}
```

First the program goes to `B::internal_init()` as expected.
Then, to `A::init()` (I guess since B derives from A , and B doesnt have any `init()`).
Now what?

what `internal_init()` it will choose? since it goes to `B::internal_init()`,the program will go into and infinite loop, and I don't understand why.

- What really happens when I call `internal_init()`?
- why it calls `internal_init()` of the "B part" of the instance? Is this about "virtual"? If so, how come? Virtual functions take place when we use polymorphism (which as far as a beginner like my self understands, it's working with *pointers* of a base class that point to a derived class objects).

Comment: Note that the **first** call to `internal_init` is not polymorphic. But within `init()`, the call *is* polymorphic because the (invisible) `this` pointer is always a pointer... If you want to avoid this, you need to write `A::internal_init()` (thus forcing a non-polymorphic call) within `init`.

Comment: This is actually a good example code you got here. It demonstrates that **polymorphic calls can be hidden behind non-polymorphic calls**. This is necessary to write non-virtual "template methods" (in the sense of [the design pattern "template method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), not to be confused with C++ templates). There, a non-virtual function calls virtual sub-functions which implement details of a larger scale algorithm. These details can be implemented in sub-classes, while the larger scale algorithm is fixed by the base class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `instance` is a `B`

```
instance.internal_init();
```

Will call `B`s `internal_init()`.  Then in `internal_init()` you call `init();`.  Now member functions have an implicit parameter that is the this pointer.

So when we call `A`'s `init()` the this pointer is actually a `B`.  In `init()` we call `internal_init();` using the this pointer to a `B`.  Since `internal_init()` is virtual and we have a pointer to `B` the virtual lookup mechanism will call `B`'s `internal_init()`.

This then loops again and will eventually cause a segfault or stack overflow.

Comment: Could you please  explain why "In init() we call internal_init(); using the this pointer to a B so **it will call B's internal_init().**"?

Comment: Because that is a polymorphic call. Read the line `internal_init()` as `this->internal_init()` (it's actually just a syntactic shorthand), with `this` of the type `A*`, but actually pointing to an instance of `B`. Here the virtual call is resolved to `B::internal_init()` during runtime.

Comment: @AlexGoft I updated my answer.  Let me know if that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `struct B` inherits all functions of `struct A` because of `struct B: public A`. The function `internal_init` of `A` is overridden in `B` because you use the same function signature and the keyword `virtual` in `A`.

So now the calls are:
`instance.internal_init();` 
which calls `internal_init()` of `B`, which calls `A::init`, which calls `B::internal_init()`, etc. until a segmentation fault is given.
To prevent this (and I think this is what you want), you can explicitly call the `internal_init()` of `A` in `B` instead of calling `init()`:

```
struct B: public A {
    virtual void internal_init()
    {
        A::internal_init();
        std::cout << "internal of B" << std::endl;
    }
};
```